# Java - Unexpected behavior of 2d Array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

The following code i wrote to solve a sudoku. I am experiencing an unexpected behavior here. I am calling the displaySudokuBoard twice. one from inside sudokuFiller when `i` value becomes greater then 8(i am getting the solved sudoku array) and another call from main function(It return me the same array which was given as input).

Why i am getting different values of my array. what is wrong with the code

```
class SudokuSolver {

public int[][] sudokuBoard = {{2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 8},
                              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5},
                              {0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3},
                              {0, 9, 8, 1, 0, 0, 2, 5, 7},
                              {3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0},
                              {9, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0},
                              {0, 5, 0, 0, 6, 9, 7, 8, 4},
                              {4, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

private boolean checkNumberExistInRow(int i, int cellVals) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if(sudokuBoard[i][j] == cellVals) {
            return false ;
        }
    }
        return true;
}
private boolean checkNumberExistInColumn(int j, int cellVals) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if(sudokuBoard[i][j] == cellVals) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
private boolean checkNumberExistInGrid(int i, int j, int cellVals) {
    i = (i / 3) * 3 ;
    j = (j / 3) * 3;
    for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        for(int s = 0; s < 3; s++) {
            if(sudokuBoard[i+k][j+s] == cellVals) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
private void FillNext(int i, int j) {
    if(j < 8 ) {
        sudokuFiller(i, j+1);
    } else {
        sudokuFiller(i+1, 0);
    }
}
public void sudokuFiller (int i, int j) {
    int k = 0;
    if(i > 8) {
        displaySodukoBoard();
        return;
    }
    if(sudokuBoard[i][j] != 0) {
        FillNext(i, j);
    }
    else {
        for(int cellVals = 1; cellVals <= 9; cellVals++) {
            if((checkNumberExistInRow(i, cellVals)) && (checkNumberExistInColumn(j, cellVals)) && (checkNumberExistInGrid(i, j, cellVals))) {
                this.sudokuBoard[i][j] = cellVals;
                FillNext(i,j);
            }
        }
        this.sudokuBoard[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
public void displaySodukoBoard() {
    for(int row = 0; row < 9; ++row) {
        for(int col = 0; col < 9; ++col) {
            if ((col == 3) || (col == 6)){
                System.out.printf("\t");
            }
            System.out.printf("%d ",sudokuBoard[row][col]);
        }
        if ((row == 2) || (row == 5)){
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
}

class FeedMeASudoku {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SudokuSolver mySudokuSolver = new SudokuSolver();

    mySudokuSolver.sudokuFiller(0,0);
    System.out.print("\n");
    mySudokuSolver.displaySodukoBoard();

}
}
```

Comment: Here's [how to debug your java code](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html)

Comment: @gerrytan can you please look at the code and help me. i have not used eclipse till now

Comment: Here's [how to debug your java code without eclipse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html)

Comment: Note that learning how to debug code is a *key* skill to [becoming a programmer](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html#id2790282).  It is at the core of what people do - because *no one* writes bug free code the first time or never finds themselves maintaining someone else's buggy code. Learning how to debug is often *more* important than learning how to do fancy code tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem: `this.sudokuBoard[i][j] = 0;`.
At the end of a set-process, you reset the field to `0` (`sudokuFiller(int i, int j)`, `else`-statement, last line).

EDIT: this solves a part of the problem. The first three rows are now correctly displayed. However, the recursion does break preemptively. Now you need to debug your code further.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to show the board first and then display the result of the new board which is your solution. The calculation was fine, but the order of calls was wrong.

In your `Main()` call, switch the second and fourth lines:

```
SudokuSolver mySudokuSolver = new SudokuSolver();
mySudokuSolver.displaySodukoBoard();
System.out.print("\n");
mySudokuSolver.sudokuFiller(0,0);
```

Also, as others suggested, you should learn how to debug and look for suggestions from LINT. For instance, you have unused variable `int k = 0;`